# Projection into upper-half of a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem: given a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (if it matters, its values are only from $\pm1$) I need to find a vector that maximizes some function, and follows the two constraints:

1. the vector is positive (for every i, proj(u)i≥0)
2. the vector is orthogonal to v.

Im using a version of the gradient descent algorithm with a "projection" step to find the solution, and the "projection" step takes any vector and converts it into a "valid" vector.

I want to find an algorithm for this "projection" step, but I dont understand how to satisfy both constaints together and not only one of them.

I would be glad to get some help!

Comment: What determines the upper half-space bounded by the hyperplane orthogonal to $v$?

Comment: Do you mean that if u projects into the positive half of the orthogonal complement we get the projection, but if it projects into the negative half it is supposed to give zero?  And I second the question, what is the definition of "upper half" since the vector v is tilted?  Does that mean that the final coordinate, for example, must be positive? Or something else? If the answer to my first question is yes, then that isn't a linear transformation so no wonder you are having trouble!

Comment: What is considered upper in this case since v can be any vector?

Comment: The precise fomulation is: I need to find a vector that maximizes some function, and follows the two constraints:
1) the vector is positive (for every $i$, $proj(u)_i\ge 0$)
2) the vector is orthogonal to $v$.

Im using a version of the gradient descent algorithm with a "projection" step to find the solution, and the "projection" step takes any vector and converts it into a "valid" vector. I want to find an algorithm for this "projection" step.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Sometimes $v^{\perp}\cap (positive-orthant)$ is the origin. Is that a problem for you? I ask because I can't tell what is upper then. Luckily the origin is guaranteed to be in the intersection so it will be non-empty, but it attains that worst case for many choices of v. To simplify consider 2-d and $v=(1,1)$. $v^{\perp}=cw$ where $w=(1,-1)$ and c is a free constant.

Comment: I dont think I understood what you meant. What I think of when you say "origin" is the $(0,0,0,...,0)$ vector. Btw, it is a valid vector and thus the projection is well defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the 'algorithm' shall consist of the following 2 steps:

Step 1: Project $u$ onto $v^{\perp}$. From the problem statement I believe you already know the most efficient way to do this.

For step 2 you must realize that the intersection of $v^{\perp}$ with the non-negative orthant (this is what you call the vector being non-negative) is a (possibly trivial as I showed in the comment) convex cone.

Therefore step 2 is to project the projected vector $u'$ onto this convex cone. I have a reference which goes into detail on how to do this even in the case of a Hilbert space. This will hopefully be strong enough to handle your case as well. Actually when proceeding algorithmically for large n you will likely employ these approximation methods.

Projections onto convex cones in Hilbert space, John M. Ingram, M.M. Marsh ,Journal of Approximation Theory, Volume 64, Issue 3, March 1991, Pages 343-350

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002190459190067K

Hopefully it was helpful. Sorry for outsourcing the crux of the problem to a reference. It is just that the statement is a bit too generic to fully resolve it in a small post here.